# How should I pass the credentials to SparqlRemoteEndpoint class object?

Tags: sparql, graphdb, dotnetrdf

I am using GraphDB database. I want `SparqlRemoteEndpoint` class object ([link](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Query_SparqlRemoteEndpoint.htm)) to connect with my database.
But, while I am putting my credentials using `setCredentials(username, password)` it says `401 unauthorized` as it uses digest authentication and GraphDB uses basic authentication:

The code is :

```
string query = "SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 50";
var endpoint = new VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://localhost:7200/repositories/786"));
endpoint.SetCredentials("admin","admin");
SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(query);
```

How should I resolve this authentication type issue?

Comment: There is an option to force base auth: https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Global-Options#forcehttpbasicauth maybe this helps

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your comment. It works by setting the `ForceHttpBasicAuth` to `true` (It is `False` by default)

The statement is :

```
VDS.RDF.Options.ForceHttpBasicAuth = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you can use either Basic Authentication with a valid base-64 encoded username/password combinations as a header or use JWT token. Some guidance can be found at http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/authentication.html

I hope this will help.